# How to detect if page is scrollable in Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am new to Angular and I made an app using angular material stepper that has some steps and some steps have longer content and so the page becomes scrollable. So I am looking for a way to detect if a page or its content is bigger than screen height so I could show a "Scroll Down" image or animation. If it is not scrollable, I don't want to show that animation.

I know that on the right a scroll bar appears, but I want to add this anyway. How do I approach resolving this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular - Button Scroll to Top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59919034/angular-button-scroll-to-top)

Comment: check this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605298/angular-hide-button-on-down-scroll-show-on-up-scroll

Comment: You can create a directive that will hold the element reference and then make some mathematic logic for the scroll bar using the height of your container. does this answer your question?

Comment: add an intersection observer to the footer (or one other element at the bottom of the page) If it is not intersecting, it means it can be scrolled into view.

Comment: @PK2995 Yes this is something that I'm looking for but the accepted answer isn't working for me

Comment: can you add stackblitz link or check the scroll event triggering and get values there.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the document scroll height vs the window height.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  console.log(x = document.documentElement.clientHeight);
  console.log(y = document.body.scrollHeight);
  console.log("document has scroll: ", y > x)
}, 1000)
```

```html
<div style="height: 600px">
 a div... go to full page and scroll will be gone
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not what I'm looking for